# WebView JavaScript Bridge Documentation

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there any documentation regarding the WebView JavaScript Bridge? I am looking for documentation that describes the capabilities and supported data types for methods defined within the "JavascriptInterface".

For example if I define the following:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    public int incrementNumber(int num) {
       return num + 1;

}
```

If I call this method from within JavaScript and run it in the emulator, everything seems to work fine. If I run this on my NexusOne, the passed in "num" argument is always "0".

If I change the above to:

```
 public class JavaScriptInterface {

    public int incrementNumber(String num) {
       // Leaving out try/catch
       int tempNum = newRadius = Integer.parseInt(num);
       return tempNum + 1;

}
```

... everything seems to work. So I am wondering if JavaScriptInterface method arguments should/can only be of type String?

Relevant resources:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either require String args on the Java side or ensure that numbers are actual numbers (and not text versions of numbers - see [about.com - JavaScript: Strings to Numbers](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstrnum.htm))  on the JavaScript side.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

But is there a document that outlines the supported data types that can be passed in to the JavaScriptInterface methods as well as supported return types.

Comment: Never seen any such documentation. Basic data types is what I've seen work - numbers and strings.

Answer (score 1):

The only relevant official doc is here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
But no description about the available types