# Get location of image inside WebView on screen

Tags: android, webview

My `WebView` loads a web page and this web page contains some images. Are there any ways to get coordinates of these images on screen when they is clicked ?

I need the coordinates of these images because I want to play some animations when people click on them but now i'm totally stuck with getting image's location :(.

Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: do you control the content of the web page that is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Since the website is also yours, you can use a [javascript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927647/webview-javascript-bridge-documentation) to determine when an image was clicked, and in combination with [dispatchTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) you can get the exact tap location on the screen. The steps that you could take are:

1. monitor all tap events on the screen in the dispatchTouchEvent method of your activity
2. save the last touch on the screen
3. monitor image clicks using your javascript interface
4. when an image is clicked, use the last saved tap location you got in dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: Thanks you for your fast reply but all I want is exact coordinates of image on screen, this means the top-left coord and the width, height of image.
In additions, to determine if image was click, i use image hyperlink, for example `myownscheme://example.com/image.jpg` and just catch this on `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

Comment: you're still stuck with javascript though, along with a javascript bridge (if you want to do android stuff in java code). You can get the dimensions using the `width` and `height` parameters of the img node in js, as well as the click coordinates with the `event` parameter

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you (English is not my mother tongue), but I don't want the click coordinates, I want the coordinates of image on screen (top-left position). JS can do this? (

Comment: yes, check out this SO question and answer(it also works for images): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag