# Call JavaScript API from Android Application

Tags: javascript, android, api

I am trying to build a native android application where I don't intend to use WEbview for my frontend. I want to make API call to eWeLink (https://github.com/skydiver/ewelink-api) which is exposed for Javascript. How can I achieve this in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions (from easiest to hardest IMO):

- You could use a JS evaluator for Android. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418086/9398629. LiquidCore https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore seems to be the standard choice. LiquidCore's readme in GitHub has directions for adding NPM package dependencies.
- Use a WebView to execute code from that npm package. Reference the results of your JS API calls in your Java code by doing something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20377592/9398629. Using `evaluateJavascript` might be easiest.
- Re-write the `ewelink-api` npm package in Java.

Answer (score 0):

So i had the same issue, so wrote a java api if you still need it that interfaces with the ewelink platform

you can get it here if you want http://ewelink-api-java.co.zw/